# null value with example PHP script from import.io

Tags: php, import.io

I have tried the example Owl data set from using the web scraper service at import.io but when I try and integrate this with their example PHP I continually get 'NULL' as the result.

```
$userGuid = "MY_USER_ID";
$apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";

// Issues a query request to import.io
function query($connectorGuid, $input, $userGuid, $apiKey) {

    $url = "https://query.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "import-io-client: import.io PHP client",
        "import-io-client-version: 2.0.0"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode(array("input" => $input)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result);
}

// Query for tile owltest
echo "Test";
$result = query("71e57dbc-9996-4fa3-8715-c564a347d002", array(
  "webpage/url" => "http://owlkingdom.com/",
), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
var_dump($result);
```

I've tried this on a couple of servers and no joy.  I haven't modified the code in anyway.  If I pop the URL into my browser I get the dataset returned to me in JSON OK.

Anyone else had any problems with the example scripts?

Comment: Did you enable all the necessary modules in php and apache? You are  putting your input array into an array, so you json_encode an url in an array in an array, are you sure you want this? (this creates  the following json: `{ input : { webpage/url : "Your URL" } }`  )

Comment: This is the exact script from the import.io tutorial so I guess it's supposed to work like this.  curl is enabled and i've just run a separate curl test and that works OK.

Comment: Got it.  It was the SSL connection causing it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

```
$url = "https://query.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);
```

to

```
$url = "http://query.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);
```

Which resolved the problem.  I believe you can also modify the curl options to accept the SSL certificate of the site if a secure connection is necessary.

Comment: You know there is an module in apache or php which enables you to use ssl?